# page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image

Tags: wp-query

when i install and apply SSL certificate on Bluehost webhosting, indeed my site entering secure channel however discovery page request image with http address but not https address even i upload photo to media library through secure channel.
that is bug of wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your wordpress url in the settings at your admin dashboard is starting with `https://`. It is not enough to simply open the website with the https link. Wordpress has to know that your website is ssl secured.